# jQuery .attr not working in IE6 & IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

The javascript code below is about half way on my php page, I can't directly modify the radio buttons with IDs q_251_789 and q_251_790 on my page unfortunately, hence why I'm using JS to add attributes to those two radio buttons:

```
<script><!--
$("#q_249_249").hide();
$("#q249").hide();
$("#q_251_789").attr("onClick","yesClicked();");
$("#q_251_790").attr("onClick","noClicked();");

function yesClicked()
{
    $("#q_249_249").show();
    $("#q249").show();
    $("#addressTable").show();
};

function noClicked()
{
    $("#q_249_249").hide();
    $("#q249").hide();
    $("#addressTable").hide();
 };
//--></script>
```

In Chrome (dev), FF (3.6), and IE8 this all works fine.

In IE6 and IE7 the following two lines of the script **do not work** but are **not** producing any errors (According to IE dev tools -> JS debugger):

```
$("#q_251_789").attr("onClick","yesClicked();");
$("#q_251_790").attr("onClick","noClicked();");
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Or a workaround to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of setting an event handler [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) attach the [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handlers the unobtrusive way, like this:

```
$("#q_251_789").click(yesClicked);
$("#q_251_790").click(noClicked);
```

Or, use anonymous functions like this (the combined selectors is just a shortcut, but unrelated):

```
$("#q_251_789").click(function () {
    $("#q_249_249, #q249, #addressTable").show();
});
$("#q_251_790").click(function () {
    $("#q_249_249, #q249, #addressTable").hide();
});
```

Comment: Awesome!! Tried the latter and it worked great :)
Thanks so much!